# Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException Scanner error

Tags: java, poker, nosuchelementexception

I am getting this error and cannot figure out how to fix it. The class tutor couldn't figure it out. It is a poker program that deals out a hand, allows the user to replace up to 4 cards, and then analyzes it. It is designed to allow the user to play as many hands as they want, but the scanner whose input decides if they play or not isn't working and I can't figure out why.

**Here is main code**

```
import java.util.*;
public class Poker
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String game = "continue";
        Run runpoker = new Run();

        System.out.println("Enter 2 to play a hand or 1 to quit the game: ");
        while (game == "continue")
        {
            game = ((Run)runpoker).playhand();//this is line 18

        }

    }
}
```

**here is the method playhand that it is calling, that is the real main code**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Run 
{
    public String playhand()
    {
        int r = 1;
        int limit = 0;

        // create a new, shuffled Deck
        Deck d = new Deck();
        Hand h = d.deal();
        h.sort();
        System.out.println(h);
        System.out.println("Which cards would you like to replace, up to 4");
        System.out.println("Enter 0 when finished");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        r = in.nextInt();
        while (r > 0 && r < 6 && limit < 4)
        {
            if (r > 0)
                h.replace(d, r - 1);
            limit++;
            r = in.nextInt();
        }
        h.sort();
        System.out.println(h);

        String result = h.analyze();
        System.out.println(result);
        String answer;
        System.out.println("Would you like to play again? Enter 'continue' to play again or 'quit' to stop playing: ");
        in.close();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        answer = input.nextLine();//this is line 34
        input.close();
        return answer;
    }
}
```

There are other classes but they shouldn't affect the scanner.
Here is the error

```
   Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
        at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source)
        at Run.playhand(Run.java:34)
        at Poker.main(Poker.java:18)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The intial Carriage return pressed after

```
System.out.println("Enter 2 to play a hand or 1 to quit the game: ");
while ((game = scan.nextInt()) == 2)
```

is never consumed and is still on the input when `playHand` is called.

So before calling `playHand` call `scan.nextLine();`

Comment: So how would I fix that?

Comment: So before calling playHand call scan.nextLine();

Comment: BTW, maybe passing in the Scanner object to `playHand` would be better,

Comment: I made a couple changes, I set it so playhand returned a String, 'quit' or 'continue' and the while look in main code set game to whatever playhand returned. What is wrong now?

Comment: In this code ` in.close();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);` you are closing your input stream.  it can not be re-opened.  Why try to re-instantiated your scanner?  Just keep on using the the existing scanner object.  Also when you enter a number followed by <CR> you need to consume the <CR> - Ok?